# `*` in the `glob.glob(pathname, *, recursive=False)`

Tags: python

I read [glob — Unix style pathname pattern expansion — Python 3.7.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) about `glob.glob(pathname, *, recursive=False)`, but have no idea of the symbol `*`,
It seems not necessary, because

```
In [6]: glob.glob("*")                                                                                            
Out[6]: ['third.html', 'test.sh', 'second.html', 'first.html']
In [7]: glob.glob("*","/Users/me/Desktop/draft") 
TypeError: glob() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

glob takes 1 positional argument and 1 option recursive.

What does `*` mean ?

Comment: it not my question,because my question  is not *args but is  *, args

Comment: The accepted answer speaks to this syntax.